# Trigger keyboard voice input

Tags: react-native, expo

I use react-native with expo (both latest) and i try to use speech to text.

For the moment i have found two solutions:

- react-native-voice, who need to eject the app but I do not want to.
- Google api call, which is not free.

Both of these solutions are not ideal in my case.

The thing is that I can write in an input with the speech-to-text integrated into the native keyboard. But I would like to be able to trigger it at the press of a button, without having to open the keyboard and have to click on the microphone.
Is there a way to do this? In the react native keyboard doc they don't talk about this

Thanks

Comment: hi, may I know any update for this issue?

Comment: Yeah, i'm not into Expo anymore.

Comment: Using Expo was one of the biggest mistake of my career